# Каково значение вводного слова "в частности"?

Tags: семантика, вводные-слова

У Розенталя:

Сочетание *в частности*, указывающее на отношения между частями высказывания, выделяется запятыми:

1.Многие народы и народности, населяющие Россию, в частности народы Крайнего Севера,  получили письменность сравнительно недавно;

2.За эту работу охотно возьмутся многие, и  я в частности.

3.Он интересуется, в частности, происхождением отдельных слов.

Без *в частности* получится:

4.Он интересуется происхождением отдельных слов.

и другой смысл будет.

Что означает *в частности* в этом предложении:

5.Вопросы эти рассматривались в ряде монографий и, в  частности,  в специальных статьях.

Здесь монографии и статьи - однородные члены.

Если уберем вводное слово, получится:

6.Вопросы эти рассматривались в ряде монографий и в специальных статьях.

Чем по смыслу будут отличаться предложения 5 и 6?

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 1):

Понимание значения ***в частности*** (вводного слова или наречия)  исходит их противопоставления **общее — частное**.

**Эти две категории должны быть обозначены в предложении (или в контексте):** многие   и я в частности, многие народы  и народы Крайнего Севера в частности, лингвистика вообще и этимология в частности.

**Не очень ясен пример с монографиями,** что там общее и частное? Здесь нужен контекст.

Как вариант, эти вопросы (все вопросы по этой теме) рассмотрены в ряде монографий и некоторые из этих вопросов (часть вопросов) рассмотрены в специальных статьях.

Вводное слово ***в частности*** обособляется.  Не требуется обособления в  конструкции "...вообще и ... в частности", в этом случае предложная форма ***в частности*** является наречием.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь Кузнецова даёт ещё такое определение:

> **В частности**, в зн. вводн. словосоч. Употр. для разъяснения, уточнения
>   чего-л. в зн.: именно, особенно. *Обратить внимание, в частности, на
>   походку.*

В приведенном примере нет явного деления на целое — частное, а **в частности** употреблено с целью акцентирующего уточнения.

Так же и в Вашем примере: вопросы рассматривались и в монографиях, и в специализированных статьях, но благодаря уточнению понятно, что в первую очередь следует рассматривать статьи.

Comment: "Обратить внимание, в частности, на походку". Значения "именно и особенно" сюда вряд ли подходят, а вот общее и частное просматривается очевидно (из контекста). Тема статьи, вероятно, посвящена имиджу (как лучше выглядеть). Это и есть общее, а походка в этом случае важный, но все-таки частный  вопрос.

Comment: @Jasmin Я согласен, что такая трактовка (с таким контекстом) вполне допустима. Но это означало бы, что составители словаря выбрали неудачный пример. Я же могу придумать другую трактовку (с другим контекстом), для которой этот пример будет вполне подходящим. Например: следователи рассматривают записи видеокамер. Тогда лучше подходит значение "особенно".

Comment: Я не уверена, что это так.  Особенно - это "прежде всего, более всего", а "в частности" не имеет такого значения. Это простое выделение, одна из деталей, которую предлагают рассмотреть (в том числе следователи).

Comment: *Особенно - это "прежде всего, более всего"* — а ещё "в особенности" (в том же словаре). Вот в рассматриваемом вопросе (про статьи и монографии) как раз это значение и подходит лучше всего для объяснения.

Comment: Ну ладно, как говорится, спасибо за ваше мнение. Но все-таки когда мне говорят "в частности",  я не считаю, что это "в особенности".  Вероятно, у этих слов возможно сближение (частный - особый - особенный), но это где-то на периферии значений. А предложение с монографиями я считаю неясным по смыслу и поэтому неудачным.

Answer (score 1):

> Чем по смыслу будут отличаться предложения 5 и 6?

Поскольку в предложении 5 невозможен смысл "статья как частный случай монографии" (и ещё грамматически этому препятствует союз "и"), то вероятная трактовка сочетания *в частности* такова: "**[вопросы] в своих частных аспектах**". Это логично, если учесть соотношение объемов статьи и монографии.